# What Code in Newly Created Project Call Window?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

If I create a new project in xcode, there will be a main xib

In main xib there is an object called window.

I did an experiment where I remove the _window outlet from the automatically generated code.

```
@interface SDAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

//@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end
```

I run the program and voila, that stupid window is still opened. The only way to make sure it's not opened is by deleting the window.

What part of the code display window? How do the delegate knows which window to open?

I do not want to show any window when application launch. I may want to show some windows when applications select preferences, for example.

Comment: What code through yonder window breaks?

Comment: If you don't want a window, what's wrong with deleting it from the NIB? In truth, for most apps, there shouldn't be a window in the main NIB anyway. Apple's template project only does that for simplicity and so it has some visible presence if you build and run it without changing anything.

Comment: Yea I deleted the window from XIB expecting some code to break. But it doesn't. Still I am puzzled. Latter I do want to have windows but for users that set preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSApp loads your main XIB, and the window in it is set to be visible on launch, so it is. *None* of your code is involved in this process at all.

Comment: Because the window name is window? Out of all the window there (there is only 1 I know) how do NSApp knows which windows to show.

Comment: It will show all the windows that are marked as "visible on launch" - The windows' names aren't important.